# I am not sure is the post function is error

Tags: python, django

When I press the button to post something, it will return me to the main page, not stay in the forum page and show me what I just post.

Here is the view.py

```
def forum(request):
profile = Profile.objects.all()
if request.method == "POST":
    user = request.user
    image = request.user.profile.image
    content = request.POST.get('content','')
    post = Post(user1=user, post_content=content, image=image)
    post.save()
    alert = True
    return render(request, "forum.html", {'alert':alert})
posts = Post.objects.filter().order_by('-timestamp')
return render(request, "forum.html", {'posts':posts})
def discussion(request, myid):
post = Post.objects.filter(id=myid).first()
replies = Replie.objects.filter(post=post)
if request.method=="POST":
    user = request.user
    image = request.user.profile.image
    desc = request.POST.get('desc','')
    post_id =request.POST.get('post_id','')
    reply = Replie(user = user, reply_content = desc, post=post, image=image)
    reply.save()
    alert = True
    return render(request, "discussion.html", {'alert':alert})
return render(request, "discussion.html", {'post':post, 'replies':replies})
```

Here is the html5 code, I don't know why I cannot post the full html code, it tell me there is an error.

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="questions" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form action="/" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Post Your Question Here</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="content" name="content" rows="3"></textarea>
          </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <h3>Please Login to post</h3>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Share your html code please

Answer (score 0):

Does your HTML include form tag with method="post" ? Example below
Make sure to include your button inside this form tag. All should work after that.

```
<form method="post">
</form>
```

Comment: omg, i forget to close the form </form>, thanks
but i have other problem now, after i press post, there have nothing response.

Comment: share your html code

Comment: Show html code.

Comment: html code is uploaded, thanks.